# What would happen if I send the same correlation id for multiple lookup requests to SophosLabs lookup?

Tags: sophoslabs-intelix

In the documentation for SophosLabs File Malware Cloud Lookup API (https://api.labs.sophos.com/doc/lookup/files.html), a `correlationId` is mentioned. How should this be generated? Should be unique for a caller or for each lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to generate UUID4 (32 chars) for each request and add some constant pre/postfix (8 chars) as you wish.